# load plugin from plugin cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

let's say that I have a plugin in a CakePHP application that needs some functionalities or some assets that reside in another plugin in my application. Is there a way that I can import that other plugin into my current plugin so I can have access to its functionalities (using App::import or something)

Please let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

of course you can - just as from the APP itself:

```
App::import('Lib', 'PluginName.ClassName')
```

etc